# Input that takes one , 2 or none

Tags: python, input

I would like to know how to write an input that can take one, 2 or none arguments.

x , y = input().split() # this is the normal way but it always asks for 2 arguments.

If a user enters only a single number, the program should print the same number. If a user enters an empty line, the program should ignore it.

I cannot figure it out.

Comment: `inputtext = input(...)` and then use `len(inputtext.split())` to tell you how many values there are. You can then act based on the number of input values.

Answer (score 1):

`str.split` returns a list and you're unpacking them into `x` and `y`. Just store the result in a single list variable and check the size for the number of elements:

```py
>>> vals = 'one two'.split()
>>> len(vals)
2

>>> vals[0]
'one'

>>> len(''.split())
0

>>> help(str.split)
Help on method_descriptor:

split(self, /, sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
    Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.

    sep
      The delimiter according which to split the string.
      None (the default value) means split according to any whitespace,
      and discard empty strings from the result.
    maxsplit
      Maximum number of splits to do.
      -1 (the default value) means no limit.
```